# Theano Import error

Tags: python-2.7, graphviz, anaconda, theano, deep-learning

I am trying to install Theano on CPU machine (running intel HD graphics, without NVIDIA). I get the following import error while testing in python.

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to exe
cute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Pyth
on implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warnin
g, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda\pkgs\theano\theano\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from theano.printing import pprint, pp
  File "c:\anaconda\pkgs\theano\theano\printing.py", line 19, in <module>
    if pd.find_graphviz():
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 409, in find_graphviz
    "SOFTWARE\ATT\Graphviz", 0, win32con.KEY_QUERY_VALUE )
pywintypes.error: (2, 'RegOpenKeyEx', 'The system cannot find the file specified
.')
```

I have the g++ installed though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

[As described in the documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html), make sure you have done this when using Anaconda.

```
conda install mingw libpython
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me in clean installation of g++

Answer (score 1):

If you use Pycharm on windows, following the following steps:

- install anaconda
- Change your interpreter to anaconda python
- install theano
- install mingw
- install libpython

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

ten,

```
from theano import *
```

It is Worked for me