# "g++ not detected" while data set goes larger, is there any limit to matrix size in GPU?

Tags: nlp, theano, deep-learning, keras

I got this message in using Keras to train an RNN for language model with a big 3D tensor (generated from a text, one hot encoded, and results a shape of (165717, 25, 7631)):

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to 
execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to 
Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this 
warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc 
installation and try again.
```

But everything goes well while I limit the size of data set into small. Thus I wonder that does Theano or CUDA limit the size of matrix?

Besides, do I have a better way to do one hot representation? I mean, in the large 3D tensor, most elements are 0 due to the one-hot representation. However, I didn't found a layer which accepts index representation of words.

Comment: It looks like a pretty clear error message to me and it has nothing to do with CUDA. Your theano configuration isn't correct and it can't find host or GPU compilers. Fix it and the problem will disappear

Comment: @talonmies I didn't make myself clear. My code works quite well with a small data set (just for debugging my code), such error only occurs with a large data set.

Comment: Yes, but the error message also tells you why that happens too. At small sizes, pure Python implementations are used because there is no performance advantage in trying to use the GPU

Answer (score 6):

```
conda install mingw libpython
```

Make sure this is installed. Get this answer from another post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31109547/3598832, which indicated from the manual.

Comment: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- mingw
- python 3.5*

Comment: I use python 2.7 instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your Theano installation is not complete.

There are two problems mentioned in the question's pasted result:

> WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be
>   unable to  execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU)
>   and will default to  Python implementations. Performance will be
>   severely degraded. To remove this  warning, set Theano flags cxx to an
>   empty string.

I suspect you're seeing this one even with small data sizes but it's a warning so things continue running successfully (using the pure Python implementation automatically).

> ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check
>   your nvcc  installation and try again.

This is the one that happens when the data size increases because now the GPU is trying to be used.

Both messages indicate an incomplete Theano installation. The first indicates that you've not set up your C++ compiler properly. The second indicates that you've not set up CUDA properly. You need to follow the appropriate sections of the [installation documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html) to fix these problems. Note that simply doing `pip install Theano` is not sufficient when you want to use anything other than the pure Python implementations.